Make a transformation to the canonical form: $u_x - yu_y - u = 1$
First, I consider $\eta$ satisfying $\eta_x - y\eta_y = 1+\eta$ with initial condition $\eta(0,y)=y$. Next, I set up the Charpit-Lagrange characteristic equations:
$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-y}=\frac{d\eta}{1+\eta}$. I got $u_1 = e^xy$ and $u_2 = e^{-x}(1+\eta)$. The general solution here can be written as $u_2 = F(u_1)$, where $F \in C^1$ is to be determined with the initial conditions.
Since $\eta(0,y)=y$, we have that $F(y)=y+1$ so thus $\eta = e^x(e^xy + 1)-1$ or $\eta = e^x + e^{2x}y -1$. Now what should $\xi$ be? The easiest attempt is to let $\xi = x$, so we have that the Jacobian is $J = (e^x+2ye^{2x})(0)-e^{2x}(1) \neq 0$, so the transformation is invertible. However, when we look at trying to cancel one of the variables, here is what happens:
$u_x = u_\eta (e^x + 2ye^{2x})+u_\xi $ and $u_y = u_\eta e^{2x}$. Going back to the original equation and plugging in, we see that $u_\eta (e^x + 2ye^{2x})+u_\xi -u_\eta ye^{2x} = 1+u$ which does cancel out $\xi$. I messed around with a couple of other function options, but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

There is a mistake in $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{d\eta}{1+\eta}$ I suppose that you can find it.

Yes, just fixed it. The frustrating thing is I've done this three times, at this point. Anyway, I have the same issue. Setting $\xi = x$ or $\xi = y$ does not work, even though that is what every other source on the matter (and the one example in the book) suggests. On the last problem, I got $\xi = x^2 - ln(y)$, so I guess I'm wondering if I'm expected to mess around with the functions until something works. This doesn't seem very methodical (like integrating factors).

$$u_x-yu_y=1+u$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-y}=\frac{du}{1+u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-y}$ :
$$e^x y=c_1\quad\text{that you correctly obtained.}$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{1+u}$ :
$$e^{-x}(1+u)=c_2\quad\text{that you correctly obtained.}$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$e^{-x}(1+u)=F(e^x y)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=-1+e^xF(e^x y)}$$
Determination of $F$ according to the boundary condition :
$$u(0,y)=y=-1+e^0 F(e^0 y)=-1+F(y)$$
$$F(y)=1+y$$
The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $e^x y$. Thus $F(e^x y)=1+e^x y$.
$$u(x,y)=-1+e^xF(e^x y)=-1+e^x(1+e^x y)$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=-1+e^x+e^{2x}y}$$
This is the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.
